# how to handle ios call interruptions in background

Tags: ios, background, call, interruptions

I can handle call interruption using beginInterruption and endInterruption in the foreground application but when my application is in the background, how should I handle the call interruption?

Comment: I have a recording application. So when I am recording audio in the background, when a call occurs, I can save the file and stop recording. But, in the background, the app crashes. I can't affod to lose the recorded data when a call comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the interruption handler which looks for the interruption state being kAudioSessionBeginInterruption and kAudioSessionEndInterruption. That should do the trick.

Do any processing (for interrruption handling) inside this handler.

Comment: delegate methods working fine, but how to re-activate the audio session, facing issues, any idea @Namratha?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood background processing within iOS, the call interruption do not apply when your application does background processing. If your app is not registered for any background processing it all it surely does not get any notification/interruption.

Comment: By background processing, do you mean the entry in the plist file that says "applciation runs in background". I have registered my app for background audio. There should be some way of notifying/interrupting the app because otherwise the app will just crash(and I can't afford to lose the recorded data).

Comment: The info about audio recording is vital for answering your question. So just to doublecheck: you are using `AVAudioRecorder` class, so you should have set a `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` to recieve notifications, e.g. for interrupted calls. I update my answer accordingly.

Comment: As seen from your original post, it seems you are using the delegate methods, but they are not called while in background, correct? Or are they called and your app crashes within the delegate methods?

Comment: I am using Audio queues for recording(not AVAudioRecorder class).
The only delegates that are called when app goes into the background are the application delgate methods i.e ApplicationDidEnterBackground and when it comes back to foreground ApplicationDidBecomeActive. I am doing certain processing in those functions but what I want is an interrupt or a notification for any alarm/SMS/call when my app is running in the background. Since I don't have any of those notifications yet, my app doesn't know what to do when it is interrupted so it crashes in the middle of the recording.

Comment: you said call interruption doesn't apply for background processing. Does it say so in Apple's documentation? Then what should an application do? It's not acceptable if the user's data (recording) is lost when a call/SMS/alert comes, is it?

Comment: Also, the voice memos app, apple's default sound recorder handles such interruptions when it is in the background. It stops recording when an alarm is sounded and saves whatever has been recorded until then. Whereas my app, instead of saving it will crash when this happens.

Comment: re: no call interruption while in background - this statement was before having the info about the background processing feature of your app (audio queue). What kind of interruption handler did you set up? (See also SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673381/handling-interruptions-with-audio-queue )

Comment: I have not set up any interruption handler for the background case. In the foreground, I have the interruption handler which looks for the interruption state being kAudioSessionBeginInterruption and kAudioSessionEndInterruption. I can handle it smoothly if the execution flows this way.
I tried having logs and saw that even in the background, this interruptionListener is called(which is what I wanted) but my application crashes if I run it from Xcode.

Comment: So the app crashes within your interruption-handling code? Please post some crash log and associated code. E.g. Do you have any UI update code in your interruption call? This are not allowed while in background and might cause the crash.

Comment: I solved that issue. There was some problem with a timer.
Turns out the foreground handler is the same even for the background case. 
For the benefit of others, I shall go ahead and post the answer to my question for a quick read.